# Can I know in Unity 5 who Instantiated the object?

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to get information from an Instantiated object from the one who Instantiated it?

For example let's say we have objectA:

```
Instantiate(objectB, gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

Is there a way to do something like this in objectB:

```
Awake() { var vector = Parent.transform.position };
```

Where "parent" is the initiator.

Comment: I don't think so, unless you store it yourself. After you Instantiate objectB you can set its parent to objectA if thats what you mean?

Comment: No, I Just want to know who Instantiated it, not set it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to accomplish that:

```
// in objectA class's function
GameObject objB = Instantiate(objectB, gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
objB.parentPos = transform.position;
// and if you just want to know who Instantiated it, use this line:
objB.parentGameObj = gameObject;

// in objectB class
public Vector3 parentPos;
public GameObject parentGameObj;
```